# SOLR DataImportHandler does not evaluate expressions

Tags: apache, solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I'm trying to use SOLR DataImportHandler to feed data. Configuration was simple and straightforward and everything worked fine, when I was importing only one field from root entity.

But when I tried to import fields from nested entities, it doesn't work and I'm really puzzled and stuck.

Here is relevant snippet from my dataconfig:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource ... />
    <document>
        <entity name="a" query="select id, b_id from a" pk="id">
               <entity name="b" query="select title from b where id ='${a.b_id}'">
                   <field column="title" name="title" />
               </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I try to debug import using DIH Development Console with verbose switched on, i can see something like:

```
...
<lst name="document#3">
<str>----------- row #1-------------</str>
<str name="ID">PST_210-SI.10             </str>
<str name="B_ID">6c2r3490seeqvb86pgb4c4trf9</str>
<str>---------------------------------------------</str>
−
<lst name="entity:b">
<str name="query">select title from b where id =''</str>
<str name="query">select title from b where id =''</str>
<str name="query">select title from b where id =''</str>
<str name="time-taken">0:0:0.1</str>
<str name="time-taken">0:0:0.1</str>
<str name="time-taken">0:0:0.1</str>
</lst>
</lst>
```

I think the interesting point are the 3 queries in entity **b**, where the id field is empty. It seems to me, like the **${a.b_id}** is not evaluated, but I can't find out why.

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha, as usual - after spending whole afternoon trying to find out solution, when I run out all ideas and ask community a question.. I suddenly find the solution myself :)

The catch was case sensitivity - If you look properly on the verbose XML output, there is for some reason . So I tried to use expression **${a.B_ID}** and it works!

Maybe the upper case could be speciffic only for Oracle JDBC driver.